# How can I get current route?

Tags: sapui5

Is there anyway that I can get current route name? There is a `getRoute` function but I have to pass the route name by myself. If there is a way to get the name of all routes from router object in controllers also it can be helpful for me. For example something like:

```
this.getRouter().getRoutes()
```

There is a function `getViews` but I couldn't find a same one for routes.

Answer (score 8):

Not as simple as it seems, though it's still possible w/o any 3rd party solutions.

Let's assume that the routes (in manifest.json) are:

```
"routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "",
                "name": "Main",
                "view": "main",
                "targetAggregation": "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "create",
                "name": "Create",
                "view": "myView",
                "targetAggregation": "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "edit/{id}",
                "name": "Edit",
                "view": "myView",
                "targetAggregation": "pages"
            },
            {
                "pattern": "view/{id}",
                "name": "View",
                "view": "myView",
                "targetAggregation": "pages"
            }
        ]
```

So in this case you would like to get the current name: **Create**, **Edit** or **View**.

***note 1***: In my case there's one view/controller ("myView") for handling three different types of displays, but it doesn't matter - you can
have separate views/controllers as well. (see **note 2** for more details).

So here's what you have to do in order to retrieve those route names:

**Step 1:**
Create a global model in you manifest.json

```
"models": {
        "applicationModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "settings": {},
        },
    }
```

**Step 2:**

In the given controller (**myView**), use the routers **attachRouteMatched** method in the built-in **onInit** method:

```
onInit: function(){
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                oRouter.attachRouteMatched(this.routeMatched, this);
}
```

***note 2***: If you have a multi-page application, set the event handler in your root controller or component.js. These two are always loaded, no matter which subpage you are on.

**Step 3:**

In the same controller, mostly directly under the **onInit** method, create the callback method (in my case it's called **routeMatched**):

```
routeMatched: function(oEvent){
            var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters(),
            var sRouteName = oParameters.name; // Yay! Our route name!
            var oModel = this.getView().getModel("applicationModel");
            oModel.setProperty("/routeName", sRouteName);
}
```

**Step 4**

Now wherever you have access to your model, you simply call it's new property: **routeName**.

```
this.getView().getModel("applicationModel").getProperty("/routeName");
```

Answer (score 6):

## As of UI5 version 1.75

Since UI5 v1.75, it has become easier to retrieve the current route.

```js
getCurrentRoute: function(router = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()) {
  const currentHash = router.getHashChanger().getHash();
  const { name } = router.getRouteInfoByHash(currentHash); // API available since 1.75
  return router.getRoute(name);
},
```

API reference: [`sap.ui.core.routing.Router#getRouteInfoByHash`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.routing.Router#methods/getRouteInfoByHash)

## As of UI5 version 1.46.1

1. In `Component.js`:

   ```js
   return UIComponent.extend("...", {
     metadata: {
       manifest: "json",
       properties: {
         "currentRouteName": {} // default type == "string"
       }
     },

     init: function() {
       UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
       this.getRouter() // beforeRouteMatched event available since 1.46.1
         .attachBeforeRouteMatched(this.onBeforeRouteMatched, this)
         .initialize();
     },

     onBeforeRouteMatched: function(event) {
       this.setCurrentRouteName(event.getParameter("name"));
     },

     getCurrentRoute: function() {
       return this.getRouter().getRoute(this.getCurrentRouteName());
     },

     // ...
   });
   ```
2. Anywhere in the controller (even in `onInit`):

   ```js
   const currentRoute = this.getOwnerComponent().getCurrentRoute();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I've simply extended the default router:
https://gist.github.com/ffleige/1f080e5c0769085569188302b2e12040

To use it, replace the default router class in your **manifest.json**

```
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "my.app.MyRouter",
```

Use the extend Router in your controllers like this

```
// get id of current route
var routeId = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).getCurrentRouteId();
// get current route object 
var route = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).getCurrentRoute();
```

This solution does not violent the access to private members and is tested with openui5 1.44.